# Word Basic Forms not covered in Stemming and Lemmatization

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, lemmatization, porter-stemmer

I need to find basic forms of words. i have been through alike questions. i am using porter stemmer and stanford core NLP for stemming and lemmatization. Consider following 3 sets of words A,B,C:-

```
Set      Word              Stem             Lemma
 A     Verity             veriti         verity (For all POS tags)
 A     Veritably          verit          veritably (For all POS tags)
 A     Veritableness      verit          veritableness (For all POS tags)                
 B     Master             master         master (For all POS tags)
 B     Mastership         mastership     mastership (For all POS tags)
 B     Masterliness       masterli       masterliness (For all POS tags)
 C     genuine            genuin         genuine (For all POS tags)
 C     genuinely          genuin         genuinely (For all POS tags)
 C     genuineness        genuin         genuineness (For all POS tags)
```

It could be seen that stems in Set C are equal so we can say genuine, genuinely and genuineness have some relation. But same cannot be applied to words in A and B which indeed are related semantically. Is it possible to find relation between such words? if yes then what this kind of relationship is this called if its not stemming / lemmatization.

Answer (score 0):

While "verity" (a noun) is related to the other words you give, it does not hold the same relationship to "veritably" and "veritableness" (adjectives) that "genuine" (an adjective) does to "genuinely" and "genuineness" (adjectives).

The word that you are looking for here is "veritable".

Not all semantically or etymologically related words will have the same lemma.